# prevent form from POSTing until javascript code is satisfied

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation

whenever i click on submit button it fires `alert("empty username")` but goes a head and directs me to `checklogin.php`...how can i avoid that and let it remain on the page unless the field is not empty?

```
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>       
function RequiredFields(){
     var username=document.forms["login"]["username"].value;


     if (username==""||username==null){
         alert("empty username")
         document.login.username.focus();
         if(document.all||document.getElementById){
             return false;
         }

     }
}
</script>
<form action="checklogin.php" method="POST" onSubmit="RequiredFields()">
Username<input type="text" name="username"/>
Password<input type="password" name="password"/>
<input type="submit" value="Login"  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML you're *actually* using?

Comment: i don't understand how this is supposed to work, as you are not calling the function, but i think the solution is something around adding a onclick in the submit that returns false if fields are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="return RequiredFields()" />
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using `onclick` rather than `onsubmit` as in the other answers?

Comment: `onclick` gets called when the button gets clicked. `onsubmit` also gets called when the user presses enter. This is why you should mostly (if not always) use onsubmit when checking submit buttons.

Answer (score 2):

in the submit input you can add the event handler of onsubmit like this:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit form" onsubmit="return RequiredFields();"/>
```

the RequiredFields will return false if not all the required fields are full and the submit process will stop.

Answer (score 2):

When you change your submit to this it won't submit if RequiredFields returns `false`.

```
<input type="submit" value="Login" onsubmit="return RequiredFields();"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work.

```
   function xyz(event)
    {
      event.preventDefault(); // while the function returns false
    }
```

also you may use HTML5 attribute **required** to avoid javascript overburden.
         **<**input type="" required***>*